# Detect OkHttp request was processed by server but client failed reading the response

Tags: android, http, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Say that the one client makes one HTTP request and the request:

- arrives to the server and the server process it successfully. It makes effects on the server database, etc.
- when the client is reading back the response, something happens (disconnects?) and the client sees an `IOException` instead of an HTTP `20X`.

Hence, the client believes the request was unsuccessful, but the it actually made an effect in the server.

Is there any way to detect this condition in the client?

Is it possible to tell apart the case of the request not arriving to the server to the case of the request arriving to the server but failing to read the response?
Maybe reading any header from the response, or analysing the exception in some way?

In my scenario the client is android, kotlin, using `Retrofit` and `OkHttp`.

PS: I am aware of solutions based on idempotency ids so that the server would at least not process two identical requests in the case the client retries, but I would like to detect the scenario in the client in the first place.

Comment: That depends on what IOException you get. If the connection was interrupted while sending the response the only way would be to include a unique ID in the requests so that the client could re-send it (and the server knows that the request with that ID had already been processed and just re-generates the response). But some time it is the server itself, e.g. it failles while processing the requests at a time where some data has already been modified in a persistent way then you can not change this on client side.